# What is the syntax for adding a row to a table that has an auto-incremented column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm new to SQL and have a question about how to insert a row into a table that has an auto-incremented column. In my script I create the table

```
CREATE TABLE orgs ( O_Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1), org varchar (255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (O_Id) );
```

which is supposed to look like

```
                   orgs
-----------------------------------------------------
      O_Id           |            orgname
-----------------------------------------------------
        1            |          "StackOverflow"
-----------------------------------------------------
        2            |          "Madoff Investments"
```

However, I don't know how to insert rows into this table. W3Schools shows the syntax

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
> VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
> ```

but I'm not sure how to use that when one of the columns is auto-incremented. I've tried

```
INSERT INTO orgs (O_id, orgname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'StackOverflow');
```

but get the error

> DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

I've also tried overriding,

```
INSERT INTO orgs (O_id, orgname) VALUES (1, 'StackOverflow');
```

but get the error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'orgs' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Simply omit the first column and pass the non-key values only.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro you should expand your comment into an answer to get the credit for it!

Comment: @FiredfromAmazon.com can you show your updated insert statement?

Answer (score 2):

```
insert orgs 
        (orgname) 
    values 
        ('StackOverflow')
```

That's the benefit of the IDENTITY designation; those values are incremented and assigned automatically for you.

Now, if you actually need to insert specific values (say you're seeding a template database with known data, or something), you can do this:

```
set @@IDENTITY_INSERT orgs ON
insert orgs 
        (O_id, orgname) 
    values 
        (1, 'StackOverflow')
set @@IDENTITY_INSERT orgs OFF
```

Setting `@@IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` for that table means to allow you to set specific values.  Normally, you wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sytax:
`INSERT orgs`
`VALUES('nextOrg')`

If the field is auto-inc you simply ignore it on `INSERT` commands.